# Rails 4 Routes Explanation for CSV Import

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, routes

I followed a rails tutorial in building a marketplace app. Now I'm following another tutorial and added csv import functionality so sellers can import products to sell.

My routes.rb currently has the below:

```
resources :listings do
  resources :orders, only: [:new, :create]
end
```

The csv import tutorial tells me to add the below:

```
resources :listings do
  collection { post :import }
end
```

Can I group them together like the below? And since the import functionality doesn't really need a url, why do we need the collection line?

```
resources :listings do
  resources :orders, only: [:new, :create]
  collection { post :import }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group them together as you did. No problem with that.

The collection line is necessary since you are creating many new records from the csv file, as I understand. You're not updating any specific record, that's why your doing it on the collection. In other words, it will post your data without passing any specific listing_id on the url.